# Overload resolution over several layers of inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, standards, c++17, overload-resolution

Consider the following example with several layers of inheritance:

```
struct A {
    void operator()(double x);
};

struct B: A {
    using A::operator();
    template <class... T> void operator()(T... x);
};

struct C: B {
    using B::operator();
    void operator()() const;
    void operator()(int x) const;
};

struct D: C {
    using C::operator();
    void operator()();
};
```

Will the overload resolution work exactly as if `D` had been written as:

```
struct D {
    void operator()(double x);
    template <class... T> void operator()(T... x);
    void operator()() const;
    void operator()(int x) const;
    void operator()();
};
```

or in the contrary, the compiler tries to find a working overload in `D`, then in `C`, then in `B`, then in `A`? In other words, does inheritance play any role in overload resolution (for functions that do not have the same signature), or not?

Comment: Editing a question in a way that makes an existing answer incorrect is discouraged.

Comment: overloads have per definition different signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general rule is that overload resolution will consider the set of declarations found by name lookup, and no others.

According to [namespace.udecl]/1:

> Each *using-declarator* in a *using-declaration* introduces a set of declarations into the declarative region in
>   which the *using-declaration* appears. The set of declarations introduced by the *using-declarator* is found by
>   performing qualified name lookup (6.4.3, 13.2) for the name in the *usingdeclarator*, excluding functions that
>   are hidden as described below.

Therefore, the name lookup of `operator()` in the scope of `D`, which finds `D::operator()` as well as the *using-declaration*, must recursively look up `operator()` in the scope of `C`, which finds the two `C::operator()`s as well as the *using-declaration*, and so on. So yes, in your case, overload resolution will consider the full set of `operator()`s as candidates.

Answer (score 1):

`D::operator()` hides overloads of parent.

You have to write using `C::operator()` (and same for other bases).

Then all overloads are visible.

Comment: Are not void operator()() and void operator()() const different signatures?